# Common commands to show up on startup of Terminal (OSX)?

Tags: macos, terminal, tty

I'm learning how to use Terminal on my Mac (10.10), and I want to have a short list of common commands that I've learned show up when I start a new tty session. Just for a few important navigational commmands that I keep on forgetting.

Is there a way to setup Terminal such that a custom message/list will appear with every new tty instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any text in the file /etc/motd will be displayed when you open a new terminal. You will need to edit this file using sudo, eg

```
$ sudo vi /etc/motd
```